# Dose Flickr block API request from Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flickr

I have a google app engine app which uses Flickr API to retrieve photos. The app uses flickr.photos_search (from one of the python flickr library) to send search request to flickr and retrieve random photos.

The app worked well at the beginning for couple days, but suddenly, several days ago, the search request is always responded with the "flickr hiccup" page. This page is usually shown when flickr's server is down.

/**************************the hiccup page that respond to my search request***************************/

[image]

The correct respond should be XML format like:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="325922" perpage="50" total="16296065">
<photo id="14204385956" owner="93558486@N04" secret="78c49af939" server="2927" farm="3" title="April in Carneros 7" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
</photos>
</rsp>
```

The weird thing is my app works perfectly locally on my development server but just cannot get any regular XML responding anymore on google app engine. The response is always the "hiccup" page. I even printed out the http get request explicitly and pasted to my browser's address bar, it also works well, which means the request is legitimate but just cannot be sent from GAE.

**It seems flickr recognizes the sender of the request is from google app engine, so it blocks it!**

Anyone has such experience? Dose flickr avoid request sent from google's server?? BTW, I use the non-commercial API key and never make profit. The request is also less than 3600 per hour which I think is the limit.

Comment: They seem to have a limit of 3600 calls per hour per key: https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my app definitely doesn't beyond the limit. Also, the same key works perfectly on my local machine. I also tried my friend's key, it doesn't work neither with my app.  The app hasn't worked correctly for almost one week. Everyday I try it and hope it come back to work again... I am going crazy about this...

Comment: After one month wait and many posts on Flickr help, it works again. Now the google app engine app can access flickr successfully. I found posts saying there is history that flickr failed to respond to certain IP domain's requests. Hope it will not happen again!

Comment: Since the middle of july, my app suddenly works fine. Still no idea why but should be flickr's problem I think.